# What log4j version is used in pyspark 3.2.0?

Tags: pyspark, log4j

What version of log4j is used in pyspark 3.2.0?

We need to identify this version in order to mitigate the [CVE-2021-44228](https://blogs.juniper.net/en-us/security/apache-log4j-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-raises-widespread-concerns) vulnerability.

Comment: I've found a nice post about this: [Structured logging of PySpark applications with Log4j 2](https://sander.ginn.it/posts/structured_logging_of_pyspark_applications_with_log4j_2/).  _Updated on December 13, 2021: This post has been updated to use version 2.15.0 which patches the vulnerability._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Spark 3.2.0 release version uses log4j **1.2.17** OOTB (see "Compile Dependencies" section in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.2.0).
It's not exposed to the "CVE-2021-44228" vulnerability (as is currently known) but also cannot be treated as "completely safe" because of the eldest weaknesses (e.g. https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-17571).